# Is inverseJoinColumns mandatory?

Tags: java, hibernate

Should inverseJoinColumn be ever defined when creating a @ManyToMany() association in Hibernate? Or Hibernate is capable defining Its value according to some field name?

And how about joinColumns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Both `joinColumns` and `inverseJoinColumns` in `@JoinTable` are optional , meaning that if you do not define them , some default will be used. According to its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html#joinColumns--), the defaults values has the same default setting of `@JoinColumn` , which is :

> The concatenation of the following: the name of the  referencing
>   relationship property or field of the referencing  entity; "*"; the
>   name of the referenced primary key column. If there is no such
>   referencing relationship property or  field in the entity, the join
>   column name is formed as the concatenation of the following: the name
>   of the entity; "*";  the name of the referenced primary key column.

But I will not relies on these default but make it explicitly to configure an explicit value for them such that other developers can also understand the codes more easily as I think most developer don't want to care and remember such default logic.